# Randomly choose track from jquery html5 audio playlist on page refresh

Tags: html, audio, random, playlist

I'm building an audio player for a web experience, that has a list of tracks. Here is the code controlling the audio player.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
jQuery(function($) {
            var supportsAudio = !!document.createElement('audio').canPlayType;
            if(supportsAudio) {
                var index = 0,
                playing = false;
                mediaPath = 'audio/',
                extension = '',
                tracks = [
                    {"track":1,"name":"track1","length":"00:55","file":"track1"},
                    {"track":2,"name":"track2","length":"00:55","file":"track2"},
                    {"track":3,"name":"track3","length":"00:55","file":"track3"},
                    {"track":4,"name":"track4","length":"00:55","file":"track4"},
                    {"track":5,"name":"track5","length":"00:55","file":"track5"}
                ],
                trackCount = tracks.length,
                npAction = $('#npAction'),
                npTitle = $('#npTitle'),
                audio = $('#audio1').bind('play', function() {
                    playing = true;
                    npAction.text('Now Playing:');
                }).bind('pause', function() {
                    playing = false;
                    npAction.text('Paused:');
                }).bind('ended', function() {
                    npAction.text('Paused:');
                    if((index + 1) < trackCount) {
                        index++;
                        loadTrack(index);
                        audio.play();
                    } else {
                        audio.pause();
                        index = 0;
                        loadTrack(index);
                    }
                }).get(0),
                li = $('#plUL li').click(function() {
                    var id = parseInt($(this).index());
                    if(id !== index) {
                        playTrack(id);
                    }
                }),
                loadTrack = function(id) {
                    $('.plSel').removeClass('plSel');
                    $('#plUL li:eq(' + id + ')').addClass('plSel');
                    npTitle.text(tracks[id].name);
                    index = id;
                    audio.src = mediaPath + tracks[id].file + extension;
                },
                playTrack = function(id) {
                    loadTrack(id);
                    audio.play();
                };

                extension = audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') ? '.mp3' : audio.canPlayType('audio/ogg') ? '.ogg' : '';
                loadTrack(index);
            }


});
});
```

Is there a way to reorder the list inside of the variable named tracks? Generating the list of 1 through 5 in a random pull? for example, the items named track2 track3 track4 ect. could potentially be played first? I'm looking for that to be random on a page refresh.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should look for [shuffling list in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a playOrder field to the tracks variable, and have a function go through each on on load and assign it a random unused playOrder number.

Comment: Oh, right on, makes sense! So the "track" field is the "play order", creating a function to randomly assign it an unused number shouldn't be too difficult, I'll try figuring that out!

Thanks dood!